# can't inject repository when use @Autowired in a non-web-application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I want to use spring-boot-jpa in my spider application, and I already have the maven dependency, models, modelRepository and the application.properties. After I use the annotation @autowired to use these repository, it will have a **NullPointerException**. How can I use them in my spider?
Here is my spider.

```
@Component
public class Crawler implements PageProcessor {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =   new SimpleDateFormat( " yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss " );
    @Autowired
    ArticleRepository articleRepository;
    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    @Autowired
    NewsRepository newsRepository;
    @Autowired
    SourceRepository sourceRepository;
    public static String content;
    private Site site = Site.me().setRetryTimes(0).setSleepTime(100000000);
    public void process(Page page) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("artiList\\((.*)\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(page.getRawText());
        String json = null;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            json = matcher.group(1);
        }
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode rootNode;
        try {
            rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
            JsonNode mainJson = rootNode.path("BAI6RHDKwangning");
            Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = mainJson.elements();
            String cur = null;
            JsonNode mark = null;
            List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                mark = iterator.next();
                cur = mark.toString();
                Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(cur, Map.class);
                list.add(map);
            }

            dbService(list);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void dbService(List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
        try {
                for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {

                    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(s + "=" + map.get(s));
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    Article article = new Article();
                    article.setUrl(map.get("url").toString());
                    if (categoryRepository == null) {
                        System.out.println("================================================asdasasdsad");
                    }
                    Category category = categoryRepository.findByCategoryName("game");
                    News news = new News();
                    Source source = sourceRepository.findBySourceName(map.get("source").toString());
                    if (source == null) {
                        source = new Source();
                        source.setSourceName(map.get("source").toString());
                    } else {
                        source.setPublishCount(source.getPublishCount() + 1);
                    }
                    news.setDocid(map.get("docid").toString());
                    news.setCommentCount(Integer.valueOf(map.get("commentCount").toString()));
                    news.setDigest(map.get("digest").toString());
                    news.setHasImg(Integer.valueOf(map.get("hasImg").toString()));
                    news.setImgsrc(map.get("imgsrc").toString());
                    news.setPriority(Integer.valueOf(map.get("priority").toString()));
                    news.setPtime(sdf.parse(map.get("ptime").toString()));
                    news.setTitle(map.get("title").toString());
                    news.setArticleId(article);
                    news.setCategoryCode(category);
                    news.setArticleId(article);
                    news.setSourceId(source);

                    articleRepository.save(article);
                    sourceRepository.save(source);
                    newsRepository.save(news);

                }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public Site getSite() {
        return site;
    }
    public void runSpider() {
        Spider.create(new Crawler())
        .addUrl("http://3g.163.com/touch/reconstruct/article/list/BAI6RHDKwangning/0-1.html")

        .thread(5)

        .run();
    }
}
```

This is my MainApplication.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NethardApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    Crawler crawler;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NethardApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        crawler.runSpider();
    }
}
```

And this is my project directory.
[image]
This is the console

```
10:05:34.602 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR us.codecraft.webmagic.Spider - process request Request{url='http://3g.163.com/touch/reconstruct/article/list/BAI6RHDKwangning/0-1.html', method='null', extras=null, priority=0, headers={}, cookies={}} error
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.cmh.Crawler.dbService(Crawler.java:90)
    at com.cmh.Crawler.process(Crawler.java:70)
    at us.codecraft.webmagic.Spider.onDownloadSuccess(Spider.java:414)
    at us.codecraft.webmagic.Spider.processRequest(Spider.java:406)
    at us.codecraft.webmagic.Spider.access$000(Spider.java:61)
    at us.codecraft.webmagic.Spider$1.run(Spider.java:320)
    at us.codecraft.webmagic.thread.CountableThreadPool$1.run(CountableThreadPool.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:05:34.603 [main] INFO us.codecraft.webmagic.Spider - Spider 3g.163.com closed! 1 pages downloaded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating an object with `new`, that object will no be managed by Spring, therefore no Autowire will happen.

But you already have a Crawler bean managed by Spring in `runSpider` method, can you just inject that one, like:

```
Spider.create(this).addUrl("http://3g.163.com/touch/reconstruct/article/list/BAI6RHDKwangning/0-1.html")
    .thread(5)
    .run();
```

Answer (score 1):

## How to injecting beans into a class outside the Spring managed context

Create the class for getApplicationContext

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
    return context;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    context = applicationContext;
}
}
```

at your spider application

```
ArticleRepository articleRepository= ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(ArticleRepository.class);
CategoryRepository categoryRepository= ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(CategoryRepository.class);
NewsRepository newsRepository= ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(NewsRepository.class);
SourceRepository sourceRepository= ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(SourceRepository.class);
```

Comment: But I have @Component at my spider application, it should be managed by spring.